# Effect of sample decimal points on power in rank-based tests

Tags: nonparametric, statistical-power, ranking

I perform different rank-based non-parametric tests (Friedman and Nemenyi) post-hoc and noticed that the decimal places of the samples have a strong effect on their power. Please consider the following toy example:

```
Samples 1: 0.12,0.23,0.22,0.17
Samples 2: 0.15,0.17,0.18,0.1
Samples 3: 0.19,0.29,0.27,0.19
```

Using all decimal places might show that samples 1&2 are not significantly different but samples 1&3 and 2&3 are. Nevertheless, omitting the last decimal place will make samples 1 equal to samples 3.

Thus, omitting too many decimal places might make the samples too similar (they will share a rank). On the contrary, not omitting them makes them prone to small irregularities in sample computation or handling of floats (every sample gets a different rank, although being very close to each other).

Questions:

1. What is the best way to deal with this, especially in a publication?
2. Is the difference between per samples described as "effect size"? In this case, rounding to a specific amount of decimal points would serve as a constraint to the minimum effect size to be considered.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "strong effect on ... power"?  What were the p values when you conducted the statistical tests both ways?

Comment: As a wrote, this was a "toy example". Thus, there are no meaningful p-values to report, I'm afraid. The point is that the test may stick with the null hypothesis although it is false (type 2 error) for two decimal places when omitting the last one. Thus, omitting decimal places may give the test a lower power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best way to deal with this" depends on whether your measurements have meaning to 2 decimal points.  For example, do you think a score of 0.10 is meaningfully different from a score of 0.12? As an analogy, if I measured the weight of adult males in pounds to two decimal places in a study of weight loss due to exercise, I would suggest that there is no meaningful difference between a weight loss of 0.10 and 0.12 pounds - since most scales are not sensitive to that level and most people are interested in weight loss of 10+ pounds.  If statistical analyses I did with 1 and 2 decimal places produced a change in statistical significance, I would not trust the finding.